# Angular and SAP's UI5 web components

Tags: angular, ui5-webcomponents

I am currently in the project planning phase and am dealing with the topic of "technology decision". The currently available frameworks are SAPUI5 and Angular with the so-called UI5 web components as the UI library. It is important that the SAPUI5 look and feel is conveyed, which is why these technologies are also on the shortlist.

I have already built a few web applications with Angular, the UI5 ​​web components are completely new to me. I am currently building a Hello World project using these two technologies and have a few questions. As an example: Assuming I build the Datepicker component (https://sap.github.io/ui5-webcomponents/playground/components/DatePicker/), how do I get the values ​​that the user enters? In general, I'm mainly wondering how the .ts file communicates with the view (html) or, more precisely, with the UI components in the view? Often the UI5 ​​components also include js code and I wonder how I can rewrite it in .ts and correctly integrate it into the view?

In summary, I am looking for example projects to get to the bottom of these questions in more detail. If anyone can help me with this I would be very grateful!

Comment: exactly the same as you do with every other form component. Have a look at reactive forms in angular. Maybe formly https://formly.dev/ can help you with your workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a official prototype application written with Angular plus UI5 Webcomponents, that answers most of those questions.

- [Demo of the app](https://sap-samples.github.io/ui5-webcomponents-sample-angular/)
- [Repository](https://github.com/SAP-samples/ui5-webcomponents-sample-angular)